# UIImage in a UIcollectonView issue

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimage

I am trying to add a UIImage to the UICollectionViewController by using the following code:

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 430, height: 550))
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "fantasy_football_hero_tile_cropped.png")
backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
backgroundImage.clipsToBounds = true
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
```

My issue is that the image is not at the bottom/lowest part of the screen which is what I am trying to achieve... how can I clip it to the bottom?! I am not using story board, can I programmatically anchor the image to the bottom as I could do in a storyboard?

This is especially true since the screen sizes for the phones are different, but the desire is still to have it anchored to the bottom.

Comment: "My issue is that the image is not at the bottom/lowest part of the screen" But you yourself are the one saying `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 430, height: 550)`. That puts the image view at the top left corner. So it makes little sense to complain that the image view is located at the wrong place; it is located exactly where you put it.

Answer (score 0):

you can add programatically. I think you add/insert some views to the self.view that will also affect simple scenario

```
let backgroundImageV = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 430, height: 500))
backgroundImageV.backgroundColor =  UIColor.blue
backgroundImageV.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
backgroundImageV.clipsToBounds = true
self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageV)


let backgroundImageV2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 430, height: 510))
backgroundImageV2.backgroundColor =  UIColor.green
backgroundImageV2.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
backgroundImageV2.clipsToBounds = true
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImageV2, at: 0)

let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 430, height: 550))
backgroundImage.backgroundColor =  UIColor.red
backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
backgroundImage.clipsToBounds = true
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
```

Here Red will be bottom Green will be in 1. because you add that red colored view later. So It will work. Can you please show your full code. It will work

Answer (score 0):

One problem here is that `self.view` for a UICollectionViewController is the UICollectionView. This is a scroll view, so no matter where you put this image view, it is going to move when the scroll view scrolls.

If that isn't what you want, there is a simple solution: set the image view as the collection view's `backgroundView`. That is a stationary view that forms the background to the collection view no matter how it is scrolled. If you set the image view's `contentMode` to `bottom` the image will be centered at the bottom, which seems to be what you are after.